# Making a game called Hack_exe

Tags: java, game

I have been making a small game which resembles a computers terminal. There isn't much in the way of a game, but before I go any further I want to know if there are any things that I can improve, or make more efficient.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main_Menu extends JFrame{

    static volatile Boolean hasInput = false;
    static String inputEarly = "";

    static JTextArea textWindow = new JTextArea();
    static JTextField textInput = new JTextField();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hack_exe");
    static BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textWindow);
    static Action action = new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textWindow.append(textInput.getText());
            inputEarly = textInput.getText();
            hasInput = true;
            textInput.setText("");
        }
    };

    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textWindow.getCaret();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Scanner in;

    public static String typePhrase(String phrase) {
        textInput.setEditable(false);
        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textWindow.append(Character.toString(phrase.charAt(i)));
            textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
        }
        textInput.setEditable(true);
        return " ";
    }

    public static String typeLoad(String phrase) {
        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i += 9) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textWindow.append(phrase.substring(i, Math.min(i + 9,  phrase.length())));
            textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
        }
        return " ";
    }

    public static String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        frame.setLayout(boxLayout);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(textInput);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        textInput.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10));
        textWindow.setEditable(false);
        textInput.addActionListener(action);
        scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);

        String input = "";

        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> openable = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> mail = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> mailCommands = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> previousCommands = new ArrayList<>();

        openable.add("Welcome");

        commands.add("ls - Lists all files in the current directory");
        commands.add("open [] - Opens the file named after 'open'");
        commands.add("mail - Opens up the mail application");
        commands.add("exit - Quit the game");
        commands.add("previous - shows previous commands");
        commands.add("help - Opens up the help bar");

        mail.add("job opportunity");

        mailCommands.add("ls - Lists all emails in the inbox");
        mailCommands.add("open [] - Opens the file named after 'open'");
        mailCommands.add("exit - Quit the mail application");
        mailCommands.add("help - Opens up the help bar");

        while(true) {
            textWindow.append("localhost " + getDateTime() + " > ");
            textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
            while(true) {
                if(hasInput) {
                    input = inputEarly;
                    hasInput = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            previousCommands.add(input);
            if(previousCommands.size() > 5) {
                previousCommands.remove(0);
            } else {

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < previousCommands.size(); i++) {
                if(previousCommands.get(i).equals("")) {
                    previousCommands.remove(i);
                }
            }
            textWindow.append("\n");
            textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
            if(input.length() >= 4) {
                if(input.equals("help")){
                    int commandsSize = commands.size();
                    for(int i = 0; i < commandsSize; i++) {
                        String value = commands.get(i);
                        textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                } else if((input.substring(0, 4)).equals("open")) {
                    while(true) {
                        if(input.length() > 5) {
                            if(openable.contains(input.substring(5))) {
                                if((input.substring(5)).equals("Welcome")) {
                                    typePhrase("Welcome to your computer, I am the Oracle. \n"
                                            + "I am the only person that is going to try \n"
                                            + "to help you get the password. Your first \n"
                                            + "stop will be to find out how to get onto \n"
                                            + "your mail application and find a job to \n"
                                            + "get you to start earning money. You will \n"
                                            + "need at least £500 to reach your next level.\n");
                                } else if((input.substring(5)).equals("Connect_Help")) {
                                    typePhrase("To connect to a desktop remotely, you need \n"
                                            + "its password, and its userID. You can use the \n"
                                            + "'connect' command to connect.");
                                } else if((input.substring(5)).equals("Mission 1 - Fishy Buisness")) {
                                    typePhrase("Mission 1 - Fishy Buisness: \n\n"
                                            + "Connect to the userID 'F15H'.");
                                }
                                break;
                            } else {
                                typePhrase("unrecognised file: '" + input.substring(5) + "'");
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            textWindow.append("Type the name of the file that you want to \n"
                                    + "open, after the 'open' command.");
                            textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                            break;
                        }
                    }   
                } else if(input.equals("exit")) {
                    System.out.println("You are shutting off your computer");
                    typePhrase(".     .     .");
                    break;
                } else if(input.equals("previous")) {
                    int previousSize = previousCommands.size();
                    for(int i = 0; i < previousSize; i++) {
                        String value = previousCommands.get(i);
                        textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                } else if(input.substring(0, 4).equals("mail")) {
                    while(true) {
                        textWindow.append("localhost.mail " + getDateTime() + " > ");
                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                        while(true) {
                            if(hasInput) {
                                input = inputEarly;
                                hasInput = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        previousCommands.add(input);
                        if(previousCommands.size() > 5) {
                            previousCommands.remove(0);
                        } else {

                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < previousCommands.size(); i++) {
                            if(previousCommands.get(i).equals("")) {
                                previousCommands.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                        textWindow.append("\n");
                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                        if(input.length() >= 4) {
                            if(input == "exit") {
                                break;
                            } else if(input.equals("help")) {
                                int mailCommandsSize = mailCommands.size();
                                for(int i = 0; i < mailCommandsSize; i++) {
                                    String value = mailCommands.get(i);
                                    textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                                    textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                                }
                            } else if((input.substring(0,4)).equals("open")) {
                                while(true) {
                                    if(input.length() > 5) {
                                        if(mail.contains(input.substring(5))) {
                                            if((input.substring(5)).equals("job opportunity")) {
                                                typeLoad("Hello, \n\n"
                                                        + "I am messaging you to say that we have noted you \n"
                                                        + "skills as a hacker and want you to help us take \n"
                                                        + "down the local competnition. We have sent you some \n"
                                                        + "files on email, and have sent an application to let \n"
                                                        + "you remotely access their computer. Their password \n"
                                                        + "is 'FishingIsFun'. We will message you later with \n"
                                                        + "further details. We will speak later.\n\n"
                                                        + "All About The Bass\n");
                                                if(mail.contains("Useful things")) {

                                                } else {
                                                    mail.add("Useful things");
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            } else if((input.substring(5)).equals("Useful things")) {
                                                if(openable.contains("Connect_Help") && openable.contains("Mission 1 - Fishy Buisness")) {

                                                } else {
                                                    typePhrase("Downloading files .   .   .   . \n"
                                                            + "Unpackaging scripts .   .   .   . \n"
                                                            + "Exporting packages .   .   .   . \n"
                                                            + "Done\n");
                                                    openable.add("Connect_Help");
                                                    openable.add("Mission 1 - Fishy Buisness");
                                                    commands.add("connect - remotely connect to the chosen machine");
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            typePhrase("unrecognised mail: '" + input + "'\n");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        textWindow.append("Type the name of the mail that you want to \n"
                                                + "open, after the 'open' command.");
                                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if(input.equals("previous")) {
                                int previousSize = previousCommands.size();
                                for(int i = 0; i < previousSize; i++) {
                                    String value = previousCommands.get(i);
                                    textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                                    textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                                }

                            } else {
                                typePhrase("unrecognised command: '" + input + "'\n");
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(input.equals("ls")) {
                                int mailSize = mail.size();
                                for(int i = 0; i < mailSize; i++) {
                                    String value = mail.get(i);
                                    textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                                    textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                                }
                            } else {
                                typePhrase("unrecognised command: '" + input + "'\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    typePhrase("unrecognised command: '" + input + "'\n");
                }
            } else {
                if(input.equals("ls")){
                    int openableSize = openable.size();
                    for(int i = 0; i < openableSize; i++) {
                        String value = openable.get(i);
                        textWindow.append(value + "\n");
                        textWindow.setCaretPosition(textWindow.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                } else {
                    typePhrase("unrecognised command: '" + input + "'\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recomment to fix the warnings instead of suppressing them in first place.

Concerning performance, you don't need to create a new `SimpleDateFormat` every time you want to create a new `getDateTime()` response, so refactor it to a private field.

`typePhrase(...)` and `typeLoad(...)` are very similar and therefore are a good point for refactoring. You could f.e. pass the increment step through the parameter. As both return only a blank character you can simply replace this with changing the return type to void. Performancewise just printing the whole text at once is probably better then iterating and sleeping for 50ms per/every 9th character.

To avoid the large if/else block at the bottom, refactor this structure using a [command pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm). Your input handling can therefore be refactored to a class `Console` or the like which keeps track of registered commands and iterates on an input-event through all registered commands and on a match executes the respective command logic. While this may not yield a noticable speed improvement (but at this time it is way to early to (over-)optimize your application), it makes your code much more readable and therefore understandable. Also, through the use of patterns you may reduce the documentation overhead as patterns depict common knowledge.

And I highly recommend to start documenting your application early. If you stop your project and return a couple of weeks later you will thank yourself if you added some documentation so you know what which methods is (or should) doing.

Last but not least, avoid `while(true) { ... }` constructs if possible.

---

Update:

Througout your code you have a loop that waits for input:

```
while(true) {
    if(hasInput) {
        input = inputEarly;
        hasInput = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

which basically should wait for input and proceeds after input was found. In terms of performance this will cause a thread to work at full capacity. If you have multiple threads that will wait for input, this will drastically slow down your application. To avoid that you can use [`wait()` and `notify()`](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) construct or better its replacement located in `java.util.concurrent` package `Lock`. The input itself should be checked in an own IO handler thread to gain the possibility to react on input events even though the rendering takes place.

On analyzing your code further I found this gem:

```
previousCommands.add(input);
if(previousCommands.size() > 5) {
    previousCommands.remove(0);
} else {

}
for(int i = 0; i < previousCommands.size(); i++) {
    if(previousCommands.get(i).equals("")) {
        previousCommands.remove(i);
    }
}
```

First, remove the empty else block if you don't need it. Why do you allow to add an empty `previousCommand` if you later on remove it anyway? Just don't add it in first place so you can avoid the latter iteration which might not work as removing entries while iterating is not possible to my knowledge unsless you explicitely use an iterator and invoke the remove on the iterator object.

Refactor equal code lines to a method and invoke the method instead of keeping the duplicate code like your wait for input or previous command handling.

Comment: What do you suggest I use instead of `while(true) { ... }`?

Comment: @Shaydoth I've updated my post to give you an example how you can replace the the wait for input loop through usage of lock or wait/notify. I've also updated my comment to avoid further unneeded loops

Answer (score 1):

Reduce nesting, create functions or even better: other classes, for all those if else statements.

Comment: nesting? What is nesting?

Comment: @Shaydoth If you put multiple if/else blocks into other if/else blocks. As you usually indent the inner blocks this is called nesting.